# mongo generate random sha1 per post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

How can I randomly generate sha1 everytime a post request happens upon login? At the moment I'm only doing `req.body.username` which pass me the username and hashing it like `sha1(req.body.username)` generates me encrypted string however that will always be the same because its based on the username.

Is it possible to generate random hash based on username alone?

I thought forEach would do but its giving me the same hash everytime too unless I'm doing it wrong.

```
 User.find(req.body, function (err, results){
    if (err) throw err;

    if (results && results.length === 1){
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var element = results[i];
            console.log(element);
            console.log('new key per request', sha1(element));
        }
        res.json(sha1(req.body.username));
    }
})
```

Edit: I'm hashing it so I can pass this to the localStorage to act as a sessionkey, its probably not the best and secure way but not sure how I'd generate a sessionKey in mongoDB.

Using sha1 and crypto, I combined sha1 and crypto to generate random keys although only crypto that's changing. The sha1 part is just the username being encrypted then adding `crypto.toString('hex')` of 32byte. I know its not the best way of creating a localStorage value identifier.

```
var buf = crypto.randomBytes(32);
            hexKey = buf.toString('hex');
        res.json(sha1(req.body.username) + hexKey);
```

Comment: Do you perhaps want uuids?

Comment: I suppose, its just so it gives the user different localStorage value everytime they login. Which ever is the best way of doing.

Comment: Maybe sha1+crypto would work just fine, but if there's a better way please suggest something. Thanks

Comment: Still trying to find a best way to random generated encrypt string, can anyone suggest?

Comment: note that hashing functions like sha1 or md5 are not random; they deterministically convert strings in one direction, such that you can always recreate the shame hashed value from the same source value, but you cannot retrieve the original source value from a hashed value.

Comment: so if you want something that behaves consistently, use hashes. If you want something random, use something random. But it's not at all clear which you want or what you want to use it for.

Comment: I want to encrypt the value and store it in the localStorage to act as a session/token key.

Comment: encrypt or hash? Note that those are two very different things. Do you understand the difference between them?